# How to convert "2017-07-27T08:02:17+0200" to local date-time and zone using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-conversion, localtime

How to convert `"2017-07-27T08:02:17+0200"` to local date-time and zone using moment.js?

Here `08:02:17` is hour:minute:second and `+0200` is time-zone. My local time-zone is `GMT+6`. I want to convert that date as my local date-time and zone. I've tried this so far:

```
moment.utc('2017-07-27T08:02:17+0200','YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZZ').local()
```

But it is returning `Invalid Date` by moment.js

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

Your input string includes UTC offset, so you can simply use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Note that as stated [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/):

> Moment's string parsing functions like `moment(string)` and `moment.utc(string)` accept offset information if provided, but convert the resulting Moment object to local or UTC time.

so there is no need to use `local()`.

```js
var m = moment('2017-07-27T08:02:17+0200', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ')
console.log(m.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the local the moment itself will do, but, if you want a specific timezone, you can use the `tz` method with the location name (as defined in `Moment Timezone`):

```
moment.tz("2017-07-27T08:02:17+0200", "America/Toronto").format();
```